# Intercepting SQL Calls and Altering the returned data

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, database-connection

Is there anyway in SQL Server that we are able to intercept queries and edit the returned result set?

Here is the example. We've got a table for Products (trying to keep as simple as possible):

```
ProductID
ProductName
ProductCost
```

Now when User A calls Select * from Product, we need to change the ProductCost figure to resolve to his base currency. For this example say we need to apply an exchange rate of .98 to the ProductCost.

So in the table a record is stored at:

- ProductID: 1
- ProductName: 'TesterProduct'
- ProductCost: $10.00

When User A calls Select * from Product he is actually returned:

- ProductID: 1
- ProductName: 'TesterProduct'
- ProductCost: $9.80

We have clients for this database across multiple platforms so i'm hoping to plumb this functionality at the database level. Any ideas on achieving this?

Comment: You should use a view for this.

Comment: I'm hoping to achieve this only with changes to the database. I know i could achieve this with views but then this would require our clients to be rejigged to pull from the views which is a big development investment.

Comment: If you don't want to use a view, you could, I suppose, add a computed column to the table that somehow gets the exchange rate from somewhere and multiplies the product cost by it, I guess (e.g. a function to pull the exchange rate from a different table based on whatever conditions)? But there's no way to just automatically transform the data on a standard select of the column.

Comment: @Matt . . . Rename the tables and create views with the current table names.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think you can instead create a synonym depending on your schema set up and point it to the view.

Comment: Is there a way that instead of pointing our connection string in our web.config directly to the SQL server db, we connect it to some other app/service we control to direct and rewrite the query calls?

Comment: How do you figure out what is users base currency? It has to go as an input. Do you pass it in select? It will be better if you ask all users to call stored procedures instead of calling simple select. You could modify the result from Stored Procedure.